# How to interpolate in R but not extrapolate to boundaries

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a large set of data arranged as countries one axis and years on the other, with observations of crime rate per 100k. Many countries are missing observations, so for example the crime rate for one country might be (sample data):

```
df <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5, NA)
```

I can interpolate it with this code:

```
 df_interp <- data.frame(lapply(df,
               function(x) na.approx(x, rule = 2)))
```

> But then I get: 3 3 3 4 5 5
>   and I would like it to become:     NA NA 3 4 5 NA

I do not want values extrapolated to the boundaries, only interpolated inside of known observations.

Comment: Are you looking for `na.approx(x, na.rm = FALSE)`? Handling `na.approx`'s arguments differently results in different `NA` handling.

Comment: Just to complete @alexis_laz's comment use: `library(zoo); df_interp <- replace(df, TRUE, lapply(df, na.approx, na.rm = FALSE))`

Comment: Thank you guys I will try this

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rle` to get the `lengths` and `values` of adjacent elements that are equal in the logical vector (`!is.na(v1)`).  Change the elements of logical vector `values` between the first and last TRUE to TRUE to create the 'ind', subset the 'v1' and apply `na.approx` on that vector.

```
library(zoo)
ind <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(!is.na(v1)), {
        i1 <- which(values)
        values[min(i1):max(i1)] <- TRUE}))
v1[ind] <- na.approx(v1[ind], rule=2)
v1
#[1] NA NA  3  4  5 NA
```

---

Or we can find the index of the first and last non-NA elements with `which`, get the sequence (`:`) and use `na.approx` only on those elements

```
ind2 <- Reduce(`:`,range(which(!is.na(v1))))
v1[ind2] <- na.approx(v1[ind2], rule=2)
v1
#[1] NA NA  3  4  5 NA
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5 , NA)
```